# PowerShell ISE Login-AzureRmAccount JavaScript error

Tags: powershell, oauth

I am running Login-AzureRmAccount command from PowerShell ISE and Visual Studio 2017 and getting this error on login pop-up window:

[image]

It was working fine month ago. I'm confused.

Comment: Can you please show us the code that generated this error? Apparently you are doing the string method `startsWith` on something that is not a string. As the wuestion is now, without the code it is anybody's guess.

Comment: Just one line in the ps1 file:  Login-AzureRmAccount

Comment: Same result running from console.

Comment: Well, then I think this error does not derive from that one PowerShell line unless it is line 30 inside a much larger script..

Comment: I am having this same issue without any apparent cause. Did you happen to find out what the problem was?

Comment: Actually, updating Visual Studio from 15.9.3 to 15.9.5 fixed it.